# How to properly start Laravel 8 with Bootstrap & authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication, laravel-ui

I face the following image every time I want to start a new Laravel 8 project with authentication routes set up using the [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui) package and Bootstrap scaffolding.

[image: capture]

Meaning that the Bootstrap is not yet loading up! Therefore, I have to re-run `php artisan UI bootstrap` & `npm install && npm run dev` to correctly set them up.

Here are the steps that I use for creating a new Laravel 8 project:

```
Install LARAVEL: laravel new [yourprojectname]
Install LARAVEL UI Package: composer require laravel/ui
Generate UI Bootstrap: php artisan ui bootstrap 
Generate Auth Scaffolding: php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
Install NPM Dependencies: npm install && npm run dev
Running LARAVEL: php artisan serve
```

But now I want to get this thing straight in my head so I won't have to re-run the codes anymore. I mean, what are the correct step-by-step commands for running to have a complete and ready project?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The steps are correct. For every new Laravel 8.x project that will include Bootstrap and auth scaffolding, you want to run the following.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

Make a note of the generated /resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php. You will want to include this in all of your views.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

Comment: You can run ```php artisan ui bootstrap``` and ```php artisan ui bootstrap --auth``` at the same time, like this : ```php artisan ui bootstrap --auth```

Comment: Getting error "Vite manifest not found at: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravelproject/public/build/manifest.json`. Any suggestion??

Comment: @Kamlesh Maybe try: npm run build

Comment: @Kamlesh And/or upgrade npm globally:  npm i -g npm@latest

Answer (score 9):

Open your windows powershell or cmd do these step:

***Step-1:*** Create your laravel app by entering in your cmd or powershell,

> `composer create-project laravel/laravel [yourapp name]`

after creating app, enter `php artisan serve` to run this app in browser.

After running complete.......
Now, this is how i solve my problem, first close the present tab of powershell or cmd (doesn't matter if app have been running) and reopen powershell or cmd. This time do these:
(During these steps don't try to run your app or PHP artisan serve)

***Step-2:*** Install laravel ui by entering :

> `composer require laravel/ui`

***Step-3:*** Generate Bootstrap ui by entering :

> `php artisan ui bootstrap`

***Step-4:*** install npm by entering:

> `npm install`

***Step-5:*** if npm installation finished, enter:

> `npm run dev`

***Step-6:*** now install Auth Scaffolding by entering:

> `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`

***Step-7:*** again install npm by entering:

> `npm install`

***Step-8:*** again, enter:

> `npm run dev`

After finishing Step-8, test and run your app:  `php artisan serve`

Comment: I guess `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` includes `php artisan ui bootstrap`. So, why you are saying to run both separately?

Answer (score -1):

1. Install the latest laravel project using this command:
   laravel new (project_name)
2. Install ui package of laravel through composer :
   Composer require laravel/ui
3. After installing ui package Please install ui bootstrap
   `php artisan ui bootstrap` ater this command run a command for bootstrap auth `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`
4. At the end run a command `npm install && npm run dev` or `npm install` and `npm run dev` now you are complete your authentication system with laravel
5. Run the command php artisan serve

Answer (score -1):

You can try it from the beginning:

Create project

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blade-example-app
```

Go to the directory

```
cd blade-example-app
```

UI Command

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

AUTH with Bootstrap

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

Run Dependencies

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Run Migration

```
php artisan migrate
```

Run the project

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score -1):

Just upgrade to php -v 8.0.* & run npm install && npm run dev because in present time laravel default install vite package and vite required php -v 8

Comment: You might enjoy this info for making your posts more apealing and readable. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score -2):

you can pass the bootstrap css link 
in your layouts/app.blade.php
then bootstrap will be called in every referenced page that Extends('layouts.app')

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30737025)

Comment: This is a dumb idea. You don't get any updates on the bootstrap dependency. You become dependent on external links if you for example include a cdn link. If that cdn is down your website loses all styling. If you include bootstrap in your website manually you need to maintain it and include all the js and css files to your project.